# Access/modify variable from a child DLL

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm loading a DLL on a win32 executable with this code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD somevar = 0;
    HINSTANCE hDLL;
    hDLL = LoadLibrary( argv[1] );
    if ( !hDLL ){
      MessageBox(NULL, _T("Unable to load dll."), _T("Fatal Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
      return -1;
    }
}
```

Once the DLL is loaded, can a DLL access the variable of its parent executable, say the DWORD variable `somevar` above?

The scenario is that the actual executable that loads the DLL is already compiled and is used in production, so I can't add any code in the parent executable. I only have the source code for reference.

Comment: You can call a function in the child pass it a pointer to the variable.

Comment: Yes, if you pass the address of `somevar` to a function exported by the dll.

Comment: The condition is that the executable that loads the DLL can't be modified. I mean its already compiled and that it only loads the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the somevar variable you should pass the address the of the var. I mean to pass the var as pointer to the dll.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void DLLFunc1(DWORD* somevar);
```

---IN your code

```
 DWORD somevar = 0;
hDLL = LoadLibrary("MyDLL");
if (hDLL != NULL)
{
   lpfnDllFunc1 = (LPFNDLLFUNC1)GetProcAddress(hDLL,                                          "DLLFunc1")
}
lpfnDllFunc1(&somevar);
```

Comment: Right, however I can't modify the executable (exe) that loads the DLL. I am thinking of the DLL "hijacking" the variable somevar. I mean the exe is already compiled and I can't do anything on it except pass the DLL for it to load.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to [export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) accessor functions from your DLL, which might look something like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) DWORD getSomevar();
__declspec(dllexport) void setSomevar(DWORD somevar);
```

(And at this point it's probably best to make `somevar` not be a stack variable.)

The loaded DLL can then use [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5.aspx) to get the address of these functions and call them.  There is sample code in the link.

Comment: Lifetime of an automatic variable in `main()` should be fine, but that's a good point in general.  However, `GetProcAddress` shouldn't be needed, IIRC reverse export works fine with load-time binding.  And you did mean to export those functions from the application, not the DLL, right?